# Where can I find a large list of English books published in the last 50 years?

Tags: data-request, books

I need a dataset of books by title with their respective authors. I have tried the library of congress, but it seems as though you need a subscription to access its data? Are there any other website that would offer a dataset similar to this? I do not need every book, only a large sample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of options, though [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/browse/languages/en) is probably not one of them because of the time range. You could try using [LibraryThing](http://www.librarything.com/api.php), [Google Books](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using) (orderBy=newest), [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/api) or [Amazon](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html) APIs to run search queries. Or try to get access to [OCLC WorldCat](https://www.oclc.org/en-US/worldcat.html) or [Ingram OASIS](http://www.ingramcontent.com/pages/oasis.aspx) - talk to your friendly local librarian.

Comment: WorldCat is the easiest one.

Comment: As best I can tell, [OCLC's licensing terms](http://oclc.org/worldcat/community/record-use.en.html) are for the member organizations ... not outside users ... so you'd have to work with a library that's a member to get access.

Answer (score 7):

The [Internet Archive](http://www.archive.org/)'s [Open Library](https://openlibrary.org) project offers [dumps of their database](https://openlibrary.org/developers/dumps) so you don't have to keep hiting an API like most of the other sites that only allow searching by title/author/isbn.

For more details, see their [documentation for developers](https://openlibrary.org/developers).  The [license](https://openlibrary.org/developers/licensing) is effectively CC0 (they waive their rights, but there may be more complex issues)

Comment: That's a good one, Joe. I came across it before but forgot to mention. In case you don't want to parse their dumps by hand, this API wrapper could make searching by publication year easier: https://github.com/reklaklislaw/rest_easy